# Javascript not working in PHP foreach?

Tags: php, html

I'm using this code to get a maximum of text in a p tag. For one reason this code only runs on the first card in my foreach but not on the second.

Here you see the problem: https://gyazo.com/c3ef858fb233b21b31098fb1682a7ce4

Here is my javascript code:

```
<script>
    function truncateText(selector, maxLength) {
        var element = document.querySelector(selector),
            truncated = element.innerText;

        if (truncated.length > maxLength) {
            truncated = truncated.substr(0,maxLength) + '...';
        }
        return truncated;
    }
</script>
```

**[PHP CODE]**

```
  <?php
     $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT naam, prijs, beschrijving, id, image1 FROM salontafels");
     $stmt->execute([]);
     $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

     foreach ($rows as $row) : { ?>
         <a class="formtitellink" href="productsalontafels.php?rowid=<?= $row['id'] ?>">
     <?php } echo '

           <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
              <div class="card h-100">
                 <img class="card-img-top" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode( $row['image1'] ) . '" />
                  <div class="card-body">
                  <h4 class="card-title">
                      <a href="">' .  $row['naam'] . '</a></a>
                  </h4><script>    document.querySelector(\'p\').innerText = truncateText(\'p\', 100);</script>
                  <h5><a href="../login/index.php"> Log in </a>voor de prijs </h5>
                  <p class="card-text">' .  $row['beschrijving'] . '</p>
              </div>
              <div class="card-footer">
                  <small class="text-muted">beschikbaar</small>
              </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
       </div>
        <!-- /.col-lg-9 -->
           </div>'?>
```

Does anyone knows what is wrong?

Comment: do a parsing length into integer and try

Comment: how should your js function know which <p> to take? so it takes the first one...

Comment: Your last php `echo` statement is missing a `;` on the last line of your PHP code.

Comment: @PierreFrançois No its not, because the last semicolon (`;`) before a closing PHP tag (`?>`) is optional.

Comment: You should add the javascript tag to this question.

Comment: Why don't you just truncate the text in PHP directly?

Comment: `foreach ($rows as $row) : {` <- You seem to be mixing both the `:` and `{...}` block styles and should actually give you a parse error.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `document.querySelector('p')` returns the first Element within the document that matches the specified selector. So it just returns the first `p` tag every time it's run.

This means that these two lines are your problem:

`document.querySelector(\'p\').innerText = truncateText(\'p\', 100)`

and

`var element = document.querySelector(selector)`

To fix it, you will need to select the specific element you're interested in each time

[If you want working code, rather than an answer to your question, I suggest just using `substr($row['beschrijving'],0,100)`]